# how to configure elastic search in jaeger without docker

Tags: elasticsearch, jaeger

I am trying to setup jaeger-all-in-one on one server. If I run the exe jaeger-all-in-one, everything works as expected (using in-memory). In order to see the options available with ES, I am not able to run a help command. Now, my requirement is to specify an elastic search URL. I have set up the environment variables `SPAN_STORAGE_TYPES` and `ES_SERVER_URLS`, but couldn't find how to run jaeger-all-in-one.exe by asking it to take in these environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting it to only elasticsearch or stack like ELK/EFK?. I had tried but we cannot configure ELK in jeager-all-one.exe alone in windows without docker.You can do it by running Jeager-collector, Jeager agent and Jeager query individually by mentioning configurations related to ELK.
In Jeager collector and Jeager query you need to set up variables `SPAN_STORAGE_TYPES` and `ES_SERVER_URLS`.